# How to translate this JavaScript code snippet to Parenscript?

Tags: javascript, common-lisp, code-translation, parenscript

I have this code snippet working on the browser using JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[rel="next"]');
```

It returns an array that is empty or filled depending on the current web page.

I am trying to translate it to Parenscript inside a function as:

```
  (ps:chain document query-selector-all ...)
```

I am unable to figure out how to translate the placement of `[rel="next"]` as an argument to the function call. Could someone give a hint?

Obs.: I am using Common Lisp/SBCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(ps:chain document (query-selector-all "[rel=\"next\"]"))
```